# NameError: name 'long_function_name' is not defined

Tags: python-3.7

Alguien Sabe por que me aparece esto?, apenas estoy empezando en Python y estoy desde el interprete[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para definirla 

def long_function_name(val1, val2, val3, val4):
   print(val1 + val2) 

te manda ese error porque no la has definido, luego que lo hayas hecho puedes llamarla como lo muestra ahora si tu ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

No estás proporcionando suficiente información.
Necesitaríamos ver los comandos anteriores para ser de más ayuda.

En primer lugar, entiendo que habrás definido la función, ¿es así?
Es decir, deberías haber ejecutado un bloque de codigo del tipo

```
def long_function_name(...):
    {acciones llevadas a cabo por la funcion}
```

Si no fuera así deberías definirla.

Otra opción sería que la funcion esté definida en un *.py* que no has importado con `from {nombre.py} import long_function_name`.

Completa la información para que podamos ayudarte, por favor.

Comment: No la he definido, como se define?, es que estoy siguiendo ejemplos para aprender a utlizar el interprete y ese es el unico codigo que he hecho.

Comment: la sintaxis es la que te he especificado en el comentario anterior. De todos modos puedes profundizar en el tutorial proporcionado en la documentación de Python.
Te dejo el enlace aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions